# Getting experimental motor data for AI based fault diagnostic scheme

Tags: data, fault, induction-motor

I am working on a personal project, which is an AI based induction machine fault diagnostic  scheme.
I do not have the required funds to purchase the hardware, i.e. the motors and data acquisition board, hence have no way of getting the datasets personally for use in developing the AI.

I was wondering if any repository exists where I can get motor data for any of the following faults:

1. rotor faults (broken rotor bars and cracked end-ring)
2. stator winding faults
3. bearing and eccentricity faults would also be highly appreciated

I have scoured the internet and haven't been able to find anything useful.

Comment: I believe that this sort of data would fall under "trade secrets"...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I do not think so. I mean is there any reason why it should?. All I need are just voltage and current readings from motors with above listed faults. Alot of datasets are available on the net, they are just unrelated to what i need

Comment: Being able to diagnose and even *predict* failure in multi-million dollar equipment with only a few hundred dollars of gear is easily worth billions of dollars.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, very few induction motors are worth multi-million dollars. most researchers, and I **have** done **extensive** research, use basic 4kw induction motors, and it will suffice for me. Predicting it is even easier. But I can't go into that now.

Comment: rephrased... he needs data in form of voltage and current readings from inductiin motors with isolated cases of the above faults. i dont think anyone that has them would consider them trade secrets.

Comment: @hopeoramabo: Why not? Clearly, it takes a significant amount of effort to assemble a statistically useful body of such data, and just as clearly, that data has significant value to a potential competitor (the OP). Why would you give it away for free?

Answer (score 1):

At my previous employer, a specialist in AI diagnosis of switchgear, transformer and electric machine faults, about the most valuable IP we had was the training database of signals.

The company was spun off from a local university, so possibly contacting the electrical engineering department at your local uni may give you some leads, but a dataset which is large enough to train an AI is highly valuable information.